# How to fix "violates foreign key constraint" in Spring-Boot when trying to delete a record. Using @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am trying to delete some records from my database but I recieve the following error: "update or delete on table "role" violates foreign key constraint "fk3qjq7qsiigxa82jgk0i0wuq3g" on table "users_role" "

I did some research and I found that it might have something to do with one of my relationships being set to @ManyToMany.

I tried modifying my code from other examples in this site but with no luck.

```java
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "users_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;
```

```java
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;
```

```java
public class UserController {
.
.
.
.
@GetMapping("/admin/deleteuser/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid user Id:" + id));

        userRepository.delete(user);
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "/admin/show-users";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be here:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

In particular, `CascadeType.ALL` means that when you try to delete a `User`, that deletion will cascade to that `User`'s roles.  It is highly unlikely that you want that, for the whole point of making the relationship many-to-many instead of one-to-many would be that more than one user can have a given role.  If you try to delete a role (whether directly or via cascading delete) there are then two alternatives:

1. the deletion cascades on to all other users having the same role (and then back to all *those* users' roles, *etc*., or
2. the deletion fails.

You're seeing (2).  The specific constraint violation reported is related to *other* users' rows in the `user_role` table when you try to delete roles.

It's unclear to me whether you really want to cascade *any* persistence operations from `User`s to their assigned `Role`s.  I'm inclined to think not, in which case you don't need to specify the `cascade` attribute of your `ManyToMany` at all:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

If you do cascade, however, then you'll need to specify the individual cascade types you want, omitting `CascadeType.REMOVE`, maybe something like

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```